# JavaFX - How to create a thin MenuBar?

Tags: java, css, javafx, menubar

I've placed at the top of a `BorderPane` a `MenuBar` with a "File" Menu and a "Close" `MenuItem` inside:

[image: Thick menubar]

How can I make it look thinner like the `MenuBar`s of most of the software I use, similar to the image below?

[image: Thick menubar]

I think it must be simple enough but as a beginner I couldn't really google it. I'm not sure how to name the problem (not many useful results for "javafx menubar height", size, styling, etc.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding the following selectors to you stylesheet reduces the height of each menu element:

```
.menu-item { -fx-padding: 1 5 1 5; }
.menu { -fx-padding: 1 5 1 5; }
```

[image]

To remove the padding of all context menus, you can additionally add:

```
.menu .context-menu { -fx-padding: 1 1 1 1; }
```

[image]

And you can also decrease the font size:

```
.menu-item >.label {-fx-font-size:9;}
.menu >.label {-fx-font-size:9;}
```

[image]

Furthermore you can remove the left right padding of the `MenuBar` and decrease the spacing:

```
.menu-bar {
  -fx-padding: 0 1 0 1;
  -fx-spacing: 1;
};
```

[image]